# Is there a program like psr.exe on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, automation, screenshot, problem-step-recorder

For localization purposes I want to capture a bunch of screenshots from a Linux program. On Windows I was used to use Problem Steps Recorder which automatically saves screenshots from every dialog I visited. Is there a similar program on Linux? Ideal would be an automation of the workflow with resulting screenshots of every page and dialog correctly named and saved.

Comment: Needed for ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

I have made one called `xsr` (X Steps Recorder). You can get it [here](https://github.com/nonnymoose/xsr), but keep in mind that it's still in development.

Comment: still working well! ;)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of an automated tool to do the job, but screenshots are easy enough.

The <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> button, on your keyboard, will snapshot the entire screen and save it to a file in your `Pictures` folder.

Alternatively, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> will snapshot just the focused window.

These instructions are correct for Gnome, and I believe Ubuntu Unity does the same. Other desktop environments may vary, but most provide something similar.